# Do Response Headers affect how Chrome processes pages?

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid, http-headers, chrome

I have a Squid Proxy in Reverse proxy mode forwarding requests to NGINX, I would like to remove all headers which are giving out information about the web server, proxy etc. Currently I have **Via** header, **Cache-Control** header, **Server** header, and a couple more. The only header I actually need is the Cache-Control and I want to get rid of the rest. I can easily remove the headers from Squid, but when I do this it takes 1min to load the page... I assume Chrome needs some of the headers to work properly. Can someone please explain if any of the headers are particularly important for Chrome or my problem is somewhere else ? The headers I really want to remove are the Server header and the Via header...

Thanks